# VM error filed to extend swap file from 0KB to 1048576 KB

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-server

I am having an ESXI host with 35 VM's I am getting an error mentioned below

> Filed to start the virtual machine.
>   Failed to power on VM.
>   Could not power on VM : msg.vmk.status.VMK_NO_SPACE.
>   Current swap file size is 0 KB.
>   Failed to extend Swap file from 0KB to 1048576 KB.

I have windows VM running and some of the host are giving this error, I have understood one thing that there is not space to create swap file. How do I resolve this.

I have seen 3 solutions in this [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004082)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution for this question was from the link mentioned.

```
Connect directly to your host or to your vCenter Server using the VMware Infrastructure/vSphere Client.
Click the Configuration tab for the ESXi/ESX host.
Click Virtual Machine Swapfile Location and click Edit.
Specify the datastore where you want to store the virtual machine swap files.
To complete the action the virtual machine will need to be powered off, then powered on.
Ensure the swap file is located on the specified host datastore.
```